# PIC16F877A with bluetooth hc-06

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, pic

I try to connect pic microcontroller PIC16F877A with pc via bluetooth hc-06.

Before I use bluetooth, I have tried to send data via serial cable, and open it with hyperterminal, and I have no problem with this system.

But when I try with bluetooth and open it with hyperterminal, it come with strange character, I suspect this happen because of the baud rate. But I set the PIC and hyperterminal with the same baud rate. I use 9600 8n+1 with no parity.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have access to an oscilloscope? That's the fastest way to check the signals between the PIC and the HC-06.

Answer (score 0):

One of the documentations [(link here)](http://www.mcu-turkey.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/HC-Serial-Bluetooth-Products-201104.pdf) says that there are 2 ways to turn the module on: the way1 with baudrate 38400 and the way2 with baudrate 9600.
Also in the hyperterminal settings try to change the Emulation from 'ANSI' to 'VT100'